# Pandas merge dataframes on same column

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am writing a scraper and I want loop through a list of links and merge all results as columns to a dataframe on same key (like a left join).

I run this code in the Ipython Notebook, the resulting csv that comes from the dataframe does not make sense, however if after running the script I merge df and df2 on the mutual column "questions", I get the join that I need, but in the script there's something wrong.

Here's the whole script, there's log in with requests but you don't have to make a user, you can run it as a guest and you just won't get all answers in the review.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import csv
import pandas as pd

get_url = 'https://www.g2crowd.com/login?form=login'
post_url = 'https://www.g2crowd.com/user_sessions'
review_url = 'https://www.g2crowd.com/survey_responses/salesforce-crm-review-29972'

links = []

with open("links.csv", "r") as f:
    spamreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        links.append(row)
links = links[1:]

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(get_url)
soup = bs(r.text)
token = soup.select('input[name="authenticity_token"]')[0]['value']
username = 'email@gmail.com'
password = 'password'

payload = {"user_session[login_email]": "email@gmail.com", "user_session[password]": "password"}
payload['authenticity_token'] = token
Referer = dict(Referer=get_url)
r = s.post(post_url, data=payload, headers=Referer)
print r.status_code

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
#df = df.set_index('questions')
for link in links:
    r = s.get(link[0])
    soup = bs(r.text)
    title = soup.title.contents[0]
    question_wrapper = soup.findAll("div", class_="question-wrapper")
    print len(question_wrapper)
    questions = []
    answers = []
    scraped_titles = []
    tricky_title = 'Salesforce CRM Review by G2 Crowd User in Transportation/Trucking/Railroad - March 13, 2013'
    with open("scraped_titles.csv", "r") as f:
        spamreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in spamreader:
            scraped_titles.append(row[0])
        scraped_titles = set(scraped_titles)
        if (title not in scraped_titles and title != tricky_title):
            for question in question_wrapper:
                q = question.label.contents[0]
                a = question.div.contents[0].text
                questions.append(q)
                answers.append(a)
                #qa = zip(questions, answers)
                qa = dict(questions=questions, answers=answers)
                df2 = pd.DataFrame(qa)
                #df2 = df2.set_index('questions', inplace=True)
                #df2.to_csv(title + ".csv", encoding='utf-8')
                df = pd.merge(df, df2, how='left', on='questions')

            with open("scraped_titles.csv", "a") as csvwriter:
                spamreader = csv.writer(csvwriter, delimiter=',')
                spamreader.writerow([unicode(title).encode("utf-8")])
        else:
            pass
df.to_csv("all_data.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

I also tried to save every review to .csv and then merge everything with Pandas, but I get a weird, rare undocumented error:

> Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open 
>   the file in universal-newline mode?

I have been trying to find my error for a pretty while, if somebody can point it out it would be extremely helpful.
Also, I hope I have formatted the post according to the rules, if not please help me to correct it.

Comment: Not sure if this is the case here... I get this error when the csv file has `\r` as the line delimiter (legacy Mac line-terminator).

Comment: @bernie I have found a post somewhere discussing this, should I traverse all CSVs and clean for \r?

Comment: On what line is that error occurring?

Comment: The error posted happens not when running the posted code, but when I save all "df2" (every individual review) to csv and then when I try to read these csv's into Pandas I get the error. Maybe clean for '\r' before saving to CSV?